# PostgreSQL result set returning from executeBatch in java

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert a value with out have batch execution will return the value that i mentions in query but it not works in the batch execution. It only return a integer array with status 1 or 0.My sample code are give below.

```
Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getDBConnection();

        String query = "insert into custom_attribute_mapping (product_id,attribute_id,attribute_values) values (49,22,'yyyyyyyyyyyyy') RETURNING attribute_mapping_id";

        try (PreparedStatement prepStmt2 = connection
                .prepareStatement(query )) {
            int i =0;       
            ResultSet rs = prepStmt2.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

In the above code i got the value of the attribute_mapping_id. but in the below code the return type of the executeBatch is an integer array and it only have the insertion status.

```
Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getDBConnection();

    String query = "insert into custom_attribute_mapping (product_id,attribute_id,attribute_values) values (49,22,'yyyyyyyyyyyyy') RETURNING attribute_mapping_id";

    try (PreparedStatement prepStmt2 = connection
            .prepareStatement(query )) {
        int i =0;
        while(i<5){
            i++;
            prepStmt2.addBatch();
        }           
        int[] rs = prepStmt2.executeBatch();
        for(int r:rs){
            System.out.println(r);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

can any one please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the generated values when using `executeBatch()`. It will only return update counts and even those aren't very [clearly defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> The elements in the array returned by the method executeBatch may be
> one of the following:
>
> A number greater than or equal to zero -- indicates that the command
> was processed successfully and is an update count giving the number of
> rows in the database that were affected by the command's execution
>
> A value of SUCCESS_NO_INFO -- indicates that the command was processed
> successfully but that the number of rows affected is unknown
>
> If one of
> the commands in a batch update fails to execute properly, this method
> throws a BatchUpdateException, and a JDBC driver may or may not
> continue to process the remaining commands in the batch. However, the
> driver's behavior must be consistent with a particular DBMS, either
> always continuing to process commands or never continuing to process
> commands. If the driver continues processing after a failure, the
> array returned by the method BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts will
> contain as many elements as there are commands in the batch, and at
> least one of the elements will be the following:
>
> A value of EXECUTE_FAILED -- indicates that the command failed to
> execute successfully and occurs only if a driver continues to process
> commands after a command fails